# MySQL SELECT INTO <variable> returns null but query returns a value

Tags: mysql, select

For some reason I cannot get this query to return a value when I do a select into.

Given a table `t10company`, I have a column called `CompanyID` which is of `CHAR(8)`, it has a value in it of:   `MYCO0001`

If I issue the following query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER))
    FROM t10company 
    WHERE LEFT(CompanyID, 4) = 'MYCO'
    GROUP BY LEFT(CompanyID, 4) 
    ORDER BY RIGHT(CompanyID, 4) LIMIT 1;
```

I get a return value of 1 which is what I would expect.

If I issue the exact same query except with `INTO @myvar` and then do a `SELECT @myvar` it always returns NULL. It does this in the stored proc I'm writing and also does it in a query window in MySQL Workbench. I dont know why?

Answer (score 2):

I use this form to assign a value to a user variable in MySQL

```
SELECT @myvar := MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER)) FROM ...
```

According to the 5.1 documentation, this should also work:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER)) INTO @myvar FROM ...
```

---

I ran a quick test (MySQL 5.1), and the final SELECT is showing @myvar is being set to 1.

```
CREATE TABLE t10company (CompanyID CHAR(8));
INSERT INTO t10company VALUES ('MYCO0001');
SET @myvar := NULL;
SELECT @myvar;
SELECT
MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER)) INTO @myvar
FROM t10company 
WHERE LEFT(CompanyID, 4) = 'MYCO'
GROUP BY LEFT(CompanyID, 4) 
ORDER BY RIGHT(CompanyID, 4) LIMIT 1;
SELECT @myvar;
```

---

The expression in the ORDER BY clause is a bit odd.

Why would you be ordering by that? The aggregate is only going to return one row. It's not clear if MySQL is disregarding that though, since MySQL may not be identifying that all rows that satisfy the WHERE clause are going to be grouped together into a single.

For this particular statement, the LIMIT 1 is redundant.

<strike>I'd suggest you try it without the ORDER BY, just to see if that makes any difference.</strike>

<strike>Otherwise, I'm inclined to agree that perhaps the aggregate function and the GROUP BY might be the problem.  If it is, them a possible workaround is to wrap your statement in a set of parenthesis as an inline view (give it an alias), and then selecting from the inline view.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "group by", "order by", or "limit" in your query for a simple max().  Eliminate those, and if that doesn't work, try wrapping another query around it.

```
select
   value into @myvar
from (
     SELECT
        MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER)) as value
     FROM
        t10company 
     WHERE
        LEFT(CompanyID, 4) = 'MYCO'
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `LEFT(CompanyID, 4)` to your `SELECT` statement (before `FROM`) if your are going to `GROUP BY LEFT(CompanyID, 4)`

Comment: it's customary, but not necessary, to include the GROUP BY expressions in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty weird.

If you enclose the query into another, it seems to work.

```
SELECT value FROM (
  SELECT MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(CompanyID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER))
    AS value FROM t10company
  WHERE LEFT(CompanyID, 4) = 'MYCO'     
  GROUP BY LEFT(CompanyID, 4)
  ORDER BY RIGHT(CompanyID, 4) LIMIT 1
) AS weird INTO @myval;
```

Judging by the EXPLAIN, the query extra cost should be negligible.